# MS Access Basic Stock Take

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Can anyone please point me in the right direction. I have created a Table with a primary key as auto number, barcode, and qty. Barcode field is set to no duplicates allowed. I have Created a form with barcode only which i will be using a barcode scanner to read the barcodes. The question I have is if i scan a barcode that has already exists is there anyway to add +1 to the qty field instead of getting the error of it being duplicate.

The idea is just to scan every single item and it will calculate the stock for you.

Answer (score 2):

A barcode scan is equivalent of entering barcode data using a keyboard and then pressing Enter. So, add to the form a button, set `Default` property of the button to `Yes` and add to your button OnClick handler something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdScan_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Barcodes where Barcode='" & Me.txtBarcode & "'")

    With rst
        If .RecordCount = 0 Then
            .AddNew
            !Barcode = Me.txtBarcode.Value
            !Qty = 1
        Else
            .Edit
            !Qty = !Qty + 1
        End If
        .Update
    End With

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```